# Why is event.stopPropagation also stopping my Bootstrap Collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, stoppropagation

I have a list item (`#planAdminMenuItem`) that has an `onclick` attribute. This list item has an icon inside of it (`.spinner`) that will collapse `#collapseExample`. Whenever the `.spinner` is clicked, I want it to run bootstrap collapse only. I do not want it to run `drawPlanAdmin` function. I have tried adding event.stopPropagation to my `toggleSpinnerLeftMenu` function, but whenever I do that, it also stops the bootstrap collapse. The parent click is blocked, but so is bootstrap collapse.

**THE PHP & HTML CODE**

```
<ul>            
    <li id="planAdminMenuItem" onclick="plan.drawPlanAdmin();"> 
        Book Plan
        <span class="icn icn-chevron-down spinner" onclick="ui.toggleSpinnerLeftMenu(this,event);" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" data-aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample"></span>
    </li>
    <!-- the collapsable area -->               
    <li id="collapseExample" class="collapse in">
        <ul>
            <li onclick="plan.drawRunListAdmin();">
                Run List View
            </li>
            <li onclick="plan.drawLadderAdmin();"> 
                Ladder View
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**THE JS CODE**

```
toggleSpinnerLeftMenu:function(el,event){
    el = jQuery(el);

    if(el.hasClass('icn-chevron-up')){
        el.addClass('icn-chevron-down');
        el.removeClass('icn-chevron-up');
    }else if(el.hasClass('icn-chevron-down')){
        el.addClass('icn-chevron-up');
        el.removeClass('icn-chevron-down');

    }
    event.stopPropagation(); //why is this stopping the collapse also?
},
```

Comment: We need to see the event handler selector for the `collapse` portion of your code. Could you post that as well?...

Comment: The Bootstrap event handlers are probably bound to `document` or `document.body`.

Comment: @War10ck this is all of the code. There is an `onclick` that already exists to run `drawPlanAdmin`, and I simply added the html necessary for the bootstrap collapse to be functional as well as a js function to alter the icon that is clicked. Do you suggest a different method of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stopPropagation` is doing exactly what it is meant to do.

If you want the parent element to be propagated by the click on the inner element then simply don't do `event.stopPropagation` at all.

Though for some reasons if you need to have that then my suggestion is: call the function like

```
toggleSpinnerLeftMenu:function(el,event){
    el = jQuery(el);

    if(el.hasClass('icn-chevron-up')){
        el.addClass('icn-chevron-down');
        el.removeClass('icn-chevron-up');
    }else if(el.hasClass('icn-chevron-down')){
        el.addClass('icn-chevron-up');
        el.removeClass('icn-chevron-down');

    }
    plan.drawPlanAdmin(); // Call the function inside of the child element's click handler.
    event.stopPropagation(); //why is this stopping the collapse also?
},
```

**Update:** Since you described the issue more clearly in the comment, which has a solution completely south of what I've written above, I am updating with the new content that may be able to help.

Instead of attaching two event handlers, one using an inline `onClick` attribute and another using Bootstrap's `data-collapse`, use one:

```
$(".spinner").on("click", function(event) { // tip: Give a better id or class name 
    $('#collapseExample').collapse({toggle: true});
    ui.toggleSpinnerLeftMenu(this, event);
});
```

This is the general idea of doing this, you may still have to make some adjustments to your method calls to fit it in.

Comment: I want the `spinner` element to just run collapse, and I want the parent list item to be the only way to run `drawPlanAdmin`. The problem is that whenever I click on the `.spinner`, it also runs `drawPlanAdmin`. I'm trying to block `drawPlanAdmin` whenever `.spinner` is clicked. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I see, I think I misunderstood your question and code, both. Will update the answer.

Comment: This worked great. The only thing I had to change was your second line to `$('#collapseExample').collapse('toggle');` Thank you!